# Broadcom BCM4352 Wifi + Fedora 22 + kernel 4.0.4-303

Tags: fedora, wifi, broadcom

```
~  lspci | grep -i broadcom
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

~  rpm -qa |grep -- -wl
kmod-wl-6.30.223.248-8.fc22.1.x86_64
akmod-wl-6.30.223.248-8.fc22.1.x86_64
broadcom-wl-6.30.223.248-2.fc22.noarch
kmod-wl-4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64-6.30.223.248-8.fc22.1.x86_64

~  uname -r
4.0.4-303.fc22.x86_64

~  lsmod | grep wl
~
```

I notice that I'm running kernel 4.0.4-303 and kmod-wl-4.0.4-301. Is the 301 vs 303 difference problematic?

I've installed both kmod-wl and akmod-wl from rpmfusion-nonfree. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check the answer about depmod -a and modprobe here: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/69411/no-wifi-after-kernel-upgrade/

After those operations, run lsmod | grep wl to verify the driver has been loaded.